# Simple channing image in vanillaJS doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

There are only 2 images, which I want to switch between each other and I couldn't find a solution.
The first time when I am clicking - it's working fine, but on the second click when I want to come back to previous image doesn't work. I think maybe (sting) condition is bad but don't know what.

```
     function exampleChangeHairs(){
        var elem = document.getElementById("hairs");
        if(elem.src == "hairs2.png"){
            elem.src = "hairs.png";
        }
        elem.src = "hairs2.png";
    }
    function exampleChangeBody(){
        var elem = document.getElementById("body");
        if(elem.src == "body2.png"){
            elem.src = "body.png";
        }
        else{
        elem.src = "body2.png";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nothing here indicates what happens on a click. Could you post that as well?

Comment: https://pastebin.pl/view/63799c18 @Sheraff

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `else` in the first function, so it will always result in `elem.src = "hairs2.png";`

```
function exampleChangeHairs(){
        var elem = document.getElementById("hairs");
        if(elem.src == "hairs2.png"){
            elem.src = "hairs.png";
        } else {
           elem.src = "hairs2.png";
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

After further clarification from you. I see what the problem is.

Your `if` statement here: `if(elem.src == "hairs2.png")` will never be true. As you would see if you `console.log(elem.src)`, it returns:

`https://cdpn.io/boomboom/v2/hairs2.png`

And `https://cdpn.io/boomboom/v2/hairs2.png` does not equal `hairs2.png`.

So you can either change your `if` statement to:

```
if(elem.src === "https://cdpn.io/boomboom/v2/hairs2.png")
```

OR

```
if(elem.src.includes("hairs2.png"));
```

Comment: I know, that was like third try and forgot to edit, there is my html https://pastebin.pl/view/63799c18

Comment: @kakaisback - I have added to my answer based on the extra html you shared. (this is why it's good to show all your code from the beginning)